# Django Mailchimp mailsnake API issues with campaignSegmentTest()

Tags: django, mailchimp

Im using mailsnake to intergrate my app with Mailchimp but im stuck here. I need to do a campaignSegmentTest and im doing it as follows:

```
conditions = [{'field':'FILTER', 'op':'eq', 'value':'test1'}]; 
print ms.campaignSegmentTest(list_id=self.list_id, options=[{'match':'all', 'conditions':conditions}])
```

I get the error msg: **{u'code': 506, u'error': u'"match" must be "any" or "all"'}**

What am i doing wrong?

here is the link to the api docs:

[API link](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/campaignsegmenttest.func.php)

Answer (score 0):

try set "options" as dict not as list:

```
print ms.campaignSegmentTest(list_id=self.list_id, options={'match':'all', 'conditions':conditions})
```

Comment: Nope, according to documentation its need to be an array. this is new error when doing it as dict : {u'code': 506, u'error': u'One of the conditions passed does not appear to be an array. If you are passing 1 condition you probably have not actually put it in an array'}

Comment: It worked for me. And read your error message. Problem in "conditions"